# request going to default url in spring security instead of requested url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security in my application and I have another application where I am calling the url **`(@RequestMapping(value = "/public/validatepassword", method = RequestMethod.POST))`** other than login url, but the request is going to **`@RequestMapping(value = "/public/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)`** instead of /validatepassword. Below is my spring security xml.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/login/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/**"
            access="fullyAuthenticated" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/public/login"
            default-target-url="/auth/userhome" authentication-failure-url="/public/fail2login?auth=fail"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/public/login" session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" expired-url="/public/login" />
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>
```

Below is my jsp from other application where I am calling the /validate url

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
         var sessionId = '<%=sessionId%>';
        var userId = '<%=user.getUserId()%>';
                        $
                                .ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : 'http://localhost:8080/<context>/public/validatepassword',
                                    data : {
                                        username : userId,
                                        password : sessionId,
                                        requestFrom : "requestFromOtherSource"
                                    },
                                    success : function(response) {
                                        if(response != "error"){
                                        $("#finIframe")
                                                .attr("src",
                                                        "http://localhost:8080/<contexty>/public/loginRedirector");
                                        }else{
                                            alert("Error");
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error : function(e) {
                                        alert('Error: ' + e);
                                        console.log(e)
                                    }
                                });

                    });
</script>
```

if I remove 
`<security:session-management>` part, then the request is going  to /validatepassword request mapping, but I want session-fixation and only one user login.

Could you help me?

below is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/public/validatepassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateUsernameAndPassword(Model model, @ModelAttribute LoginBeanDTO loginDto,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String requestFrom = request.getParameter("requestFrom");
        if (requestFrom != null && requestFrom != "" && requestFrom.equalsIgnoreCase("requestFromOtherSource")) {
            String userId = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");         
            loginDto.setUsername(userId);
            loginDto.setPassword(password);
            session.setAttribute("fromOtherResource", requestFrom);
        }
        if (!userCmdHelper.validateUsernameAndPassword(loginDto)) {
            model.addAttribute("loginDto", loginDto);
            model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username or password");
            return "login";
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("j_username", loginDto.getUsername());
            session.setAttribute("j_password", loginDto.getPassword());
            return "loginRedirector";
        }

    }
```

and loginredirector.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<%
    // This is to prevent Caching on the browser and proxy
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragmas" content="no-cache">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
        document.jsecuritycheck.submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body class="default" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0"
    leftmargin="0" onLoad="redirect();">
    <form
        action="<c:url value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>/j_spring_security_check"
        method="POST" name="jsecuritycheck">

        <c:set var="username" value="${j_username}" />
        <c:set var="password" value="${j_password}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="j_username"
            value="<c:out value="${username}"/>" escapeXml="true"> <input
            type="hidden" name="j_password" value="<c:out value="${password}"/>"
            escapeXml="true">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1.There is no other session. 2. If I remove session management then it's working fine.3. from the Ajax call I am passing user name and password and from validatepassword method I am redirecting to one jsp page where I am setting j_springsecurity with j_username and j_passworf on page load which will login and show the home page. Why it is working if I remove session management, I want to keep session management

Comment: There is no luck after adding the above and while enabled debug it is showing **End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0**. It is throwing error first time but when I click the link again which is calling the ajax then it is working fine. I am surprising what is happening.

Comment: Added the re director code. instead hitting validateUserNameAndPassword method it is hitting the below.

@RequestMapping(value = "/public/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String login(Model model, HttpSession session) {
  LoginBeanDTO loginDto = new LoginBeanDTO();
  model.addAttribute("loginDto", loginDto);
  if (session.getAttribute("user") != null)
   return "redirect:/auth/userhome";
  else
   return "login";
 }

I am not able to add the log in comment as the log texts are huge

Comment: Below url is called 
`GET http://localhost:8080/iKareFinance/public/fail2login?auth=fail`

and also I am seeing below in log.

(http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB003028: Start processing with input [invalid]
23:22:52,407 DEBUG [org.apache.coyote.http11] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB003029: Parameter starting at position [0] and ending at position [7] with a value of [invalid] was not followed by an '=' character
23:22:52,576 DEBUG [org.apache.coyote.http11] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB003028: Start processing with input [j_username=&j_password=]

Comment: But I am surprise while I click on the link which calls the above ajax call then its working fine. Its only first time not working after server start, then when clicks on link second time its working fine and removing the session-management its working fine.